# let (X,d) be a metric space. d is discrete iff X∩X'=∅

Tags: metric-spaces

Let (X,d) be a metric space.
prove that:
(X,d) is discrete if only if X∩X′=∅,X′ is the set of all limit points of X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $X\cap A=A$ for every subset $A$ of $X$, so what is $X'$?

Comment: in discrete, $X' $ is emty? ?

Comment: @DonAnselmo: Yes, because $\{x\}$ is open for each $x\in X$.

Comment: how about the other direction?

Comment: @DonAnselmo: Let $x\in X$, and let $A=X\setminus\{x\}$. If $X'=\varnothing$, can $x$ be a limit point of $A$?

Comment: defnitely not..

Comment: @DonAnselmo: So $x$ has an open nbhd disjoint from $A$. What must that nbhd be?

Comment: a singleton Brian

Comment: @DonAnselmo: Exactly.